# Programmatically Save an Excel File Using OLE

Tags: c++, excel, c++builder, ole

How do you programmatically save an excel workbook using OLE and C++ Builder?

I'm guessing it might be something like:

```
Variant excel = Variant::CreateObject("Excel.Application");
excel.OleProcedure("Save"); // but how might you specify the file name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh just found the answer from [here](http://www.jcmiras.net/jcm/item/45/):

```
excel.OlePropertyGet(”Workbooks”).OlePropertyGet(”Item”,1).OleProcedure(”SaveAs”,”d:\\case1.xls”);
```

First you get the workbooks object followed by the workbook. Then you can do a SaveAs.