# delphi ole excel container, save file

Tags: delphi, excel, delphi-2009, ole

what is the syntax for this [c++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106188/programmatically-save-an-excel-file-using-ole) in Delphi?

After using an oleContainer, and trying to do SaveDocumentAs which didn't work. I thought this might be a good alternative.

update: thank you for the translation, however the excel file goes curropted after the call

```
var
  ExcelOle: TOleContainer;
begin
  ExcelOLE.CreateObjectFromFile(FileName, False);
  ExcelOle.OleObject.application.workbooks[1].save;
end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? That question doesn't look like it will help you. It's not using a contained. It's automating standalone Excel.

Comment: Do you want translate the accepted answer to delphi ? if the answer is yes try this : `excel.Workbooks[1].SaveAs('d:\case1.xls');`

Comment: @none, not that I care too much, but I did answer your initial question. your edit makes it a whole new question IMHO.

Comment: @kobik you did answer the question asked, yet i hadn't implemented and tested successfully the solution, so it had to wait.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply create an Ole Object:

```
uses ComObj, Excel;

var Excel: OleVariant;
Excel := CreateOleObject('EXCEL.Application');
Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add;
Excel.Application.Workbooks[1].SaveAs('c:\test.xlsx', xlWorkbookDefault); // or xlOpenXMLWorkbook (51)
Excel.Application.Quit;
```

---

Excel.pas

```
unit Excel;

interface

uses Windows, Activex;

// originally from Excel97.pas
// XlFileFormat constants
type
  XlFileFormat = TOleEnum;
const
  xlAddIn = $00000012;
  xlCSV = $00000006;
  xlCSVMac = $00000016;
  xlCSVMSDOS = $00000018;
  xlCSVWindows = $00000017;
  xlDBF2 = $00000007;
  xlDBF3 = $00000008;
  xlDBF4 = $0000000B;
  xlDIF = $00000009;
  xlExcel2 = $00000010;
  xlExcel2FarEast = $0000001B;
  xlExcel3 = $0000001D;
  xlExcel4 = $00000021;
  xlExcel5 = $00000027;
  xlExcel7 = $00000027;
  xlExcel9795 = $0000002B;
  xlExcel4Workbook = $00000023;
  xlIntlAddIn = $0000001A;
  xlIntlMacro = $00000019;
  xlWorkbookNormal = $FFFFEFD1;
  xlSYLK = $00000002;
  xlTemplate = $00000011;
  xlCurrentPlatformText = $FFFFEFC2;
  xlTextMac = $00000013;
  xlTextMSDOS = $00000015;
  xlTextPrinter = $00000024;
  xlTextWindows = $00000014;
  xlWJ2WD1 = $0000000E;
  xlWK1 = $00000005;
  xlWK1ALL = $0000001F;
  xlWK1FMT = $0000001E;
  xlWK3 = $0000000F;
  xlWK4 = $00000026;
  xlWK3FM3 = $00000020;
  xlWKS = $00000004;
  xlWorks2FarEast = $0000001C;
  xlWQ1 = $00000022;
  xlWJ3 = $00000028;
  xlWJ3FJ3 = $00000029;
  xlExcel12 =50;
  xlExcel8 = 56;
  xlHtml = 44;
  xlOpenXMLAddIn = 55;
  xlOpenXMLTemplate = 54;
  xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled = 53;
  xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51;
  xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52;
  xlTemplate8 = 17;
  xlUnicodeText = 42;
  xlWebArchive = 45;
  xlWorkbookDefault = 51;
  xlXMLSpreadsheet = 46;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: This is the answer to the translation, however for some odd reason, it corrupts the xlsx file.

Comment: @none if you want to save a .xlsx file you might need to specify the format when you save it

Comment: @kobik, are you sure `xlWorkbookDefault` will always work ? Doesn't it depend on some settings ? Wouldn't be safer to use `xlXMLSpreadsheet` ? I don't have `Office` so I can't check it but [`here`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/introduction-to-new-file-name-extensions-HA010006935.aspx#BM1) they say the `.xlsx` is XML file format.

Comment: @TLama Ultimately it's down to none and it's hard to know exactly what he/she wants.

Comment: @TLama, using `xlXMLSpreadsheet` is showing a corrupted file message when I use the code with Office 2010. I've been using `xlWorkbookDefault` for ages with no problems. Here is some [info](http://www.rondebruin.nl/saveas.htm).

Comment: @kobik, corrupted ? Strange, have you called it like `SaveAs('c:\test.xlsx', Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet);` ?

Comment: @kobik, `xlWorkbookDefault` works to you for ages probably because no user [`changes the default file format`](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-change-default-file-saving-format-from-docx-to-doc-in-word-2007/) or if you want the [`DefaultSaveFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212749%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property. So I wouldn't expect that I'll give the factory default format all the time. I know it's off topic for this Q, but I'm just a stickler :)

Comment: @TLama, yes I did. `xlXMLSpreadsheet` is meant to save `.xml` files. `xlsx` format is actually `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` = `xlWorkbookDefault` (51)

Comment: @kobik, so the [`Application.DefaultSaveFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff838398.aspx) returns you `xlWorkbookDefault`, what is in your Office version the `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` by default what makes sense to me. But have you [`tried to change`](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-change-default-file-saving-format-from-docx-to-doc-in-word-2007/) the default save format to something else than `xlsx` ? Will the file be really saved in the `xlsx` format when you use `xlWorkbookDefault` flag ? Sorry for disturbing, it's more topic for another Q, but I'd like to make it clear. Thanks

Comment: i think it has to so that i have uses "ExcelXP" and not Excel. could you share the Excel.pas?

Comment: @TLama, changing the default format does not make any difference. you can replace `xlWorkbookDefault` with `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` constant when you want to save `xlsx` (so it will make more seance in code) but the fact remains that they have the same value of 51.

Comment: @kobik, thanks. So I think we have another meaningless constant aboard. I'm pretty sure the `xlWorkbookDefault` was intended to use for the default file format which is preselected when you open `Save as` dialog in a certain Office application and which is configurable or which might be preselected depending on what file format you have currently opened. Never mind, +1 for answering my questions.

Comment: @TLama, I agree, the name of the constant is misleading. how about `xlWorkbookNormal` which is meant to save 'xls'? :) you could pass `Excel.Application.DefaultSaveFormat` as parameter to reflect what you defined as "default" save format in Excel. you only need to consider the file extension according to that format.